# sample java applications

Tags: java, sample

.NET has codeplex for good sample applications to understand best practices. In Java, the first level of difficulty lies in finding a project with the frameworks you are interested to see implemented. In any case I've been unsuccessful in finding sample applications.

SourceForge.NET has many, but a lot of them are incomplete. Many other samples I find are only covering a CRUD - like Spring web site provides a CRUD, struts 2 provides a CRUD and I found some more here: http://www.learntechnology.net/content/main.jsp

None of them cover an application with decent level of complexity. I'm sure there are such projects, it's just my inability to find them.

Can someone provide the key for the treasure :-)

Edit: I got a comment asking me for specifics, so here it is:

I'm looking for a web application, built with a framework like Struts 2, Spring MVC (any action framework basically), Hibernate / Plain JDBC / JDBC templates in Spring at DAL, and no EJB's please!!

An application like bug tracker, blog template, inventory management etc.. anything that is non-trivial.

Comment: What type of project are you looking for? Your mentioning CRUD, so I suspect you are looking for a web application? If you specify what you want to see in your example people will be able to provide better answers.

Answer (score 3):

a good starting point might be [appfuse](http://appfuse.org) it is really a sort of boot strap your project kinda thing. Make sure you go for the 'full-source' option at the end of the instructions.

As for features:

1. Security, with user and admin roles
2. Sign up
3. Email templates

Comment: +1 for appfuse - a most excellent framework

Answer (score 1):

How about the Java pet store reference implementation from the J2EE blueprints?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following link may be useful. It explains how to go about implementing a project using domain driven design
http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/index.html